# Ддосят сайт через активные соединения (ISP). Как поставить ограничение на кол-во запросов?

Tags: apache, ddos

Стоит сайт на OVH. Их антиддос ловит большие атаки. Но нас как-то умудряются заддосить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

httpd.itk становится 256 и все. Причем все подключения с 1 IP.
Как сделать так чтобы как-то распределить нагрузку?

- CentOS 6.6 (64bits)
- Процессор Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU W3530 @ 2.80GHz 1600.000 Mhz X 8
- Оперативная память    16 GB

Comment: Вероятно, вам стоит обратиться в саппорт компании, которая предоставляет вам услугу защиты от ДДОС.

Comment: Если, как я понял, все идет с одного ip, может попробовать просто заблокировать этот ip?